# IIS Rewrite Rule for Single Page App

Tags: node.js, iis, url-rewriting

My goal is to be able to access this URL from remote machine via IIS Rewrite:

```
http://host:5000/#!/room/5963bdd51eeaa415988ec6d9
```

using the following URL:

```
http://{host}/chat/
```

Here's my web.config

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="chat" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="chat/*" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://127.0.0.1:5000" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
            <outboundRules>
                <rule name="chat" preCondition="">
                    <match filterByTags="A, Area, Base, Form, Head, IFrame, Img, Input, Link, Script" pattern="chat/*" negate="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="http://127.0.0.1:5000" />
                </rule>
            </outboundRules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Anything I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Yes. *localhost* is the local loopback address on the machine where it is accessed. It's not accessible from other machines (those machines will have their own *localhost*).

Comment: Hi, even when I replace localhost with my domain/host, still doesn't work so I'm curious where the error is. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a outbound rule, your client will receive the address as http://127.0.0.1:5000. Assuming the client machine has no application installed at port 5000, you will run into an error.

Try using a Inbound Rewrite rule (If you dont want the URL to change on the browser) or Inbound redirect rule (if you want the URL to change on the browser) with the same parameters and let the server do the talking.